# Cannot persist CSS changes in Chrome DevTools with PostCSS and Vite using Workspaces

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, vite, postcss

I'm encountering a problem where changes I make to CSS in Chrome DevTools' Styles pane are not being persisted back to the original PostCSS files in my local project when using Vite as my development server. This issue occurs even when I have the Workspaces feature in DevTools properly configured, and source maps for my CSS are correctly generated and included as data URIs in my CSS files.

The problem appears to be specific to PostCSS. When I configure Vite to use PostCSS and make changes in the Styles pane, those changes are not persisted back to the original PostCSS files. However, if I remove PostCSS from my Vite configuration, changes are correctly persisted.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Set up a new project with Vite and PostCSS.
2. Configure Vite to generate CSS source maps in development (using **`devSourcemap: true`**).
3. Configure Chrome DevTools to use the Workspaces feature that maps to the project's directory.
4. Open the project in a browser and in DevTools.
5. Make a change to a CSS property in the Styles pane in DevTools.
6. Observe that the change is not persisted back to the original PostCSS file.

**Expected Result:**

Changes made to CSS properties in the Styles pane in DevTools should be persisted back to the original PostCSS files when source maps are correctly configured and the Workspaces feature in DevTools is set up properly.

**Actual Result:**

Changes made to CSS properties in the Styles pane are not persisted back to the original PostCSS files. This issue only occurs when PostCSS is used in the Vite configuration.

**Additional Information:**

- Vite version: 4.3.9
- PostCSS version: 8.4.24
- Chrome version: 114
- Operating system: MacOS 13.4
- The Workspaces feature in Chrome DevTools is being used.
- [Vite.js Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5PIh.png) (Config only works as long as the postcss code is commented out)
- [Google Workspaces Limitations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzG76.png)
- [What it looks like in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNEoB.png) (Looks the same if I enable postcss, the single difference is it doesn't persist the changes I do in the style editor)